# Javascript Switch Statement On Button

Tags: javascript, button, switch-statement

Hi currently I am working on a Switch statement and I want to re-map the statement that is currently on a select input. Here is the html and javascript. The statement on the select input works fine. I now want to switch from select input to 3 buttons input. But when I try to re-map the javascript to the buttons, it won't work. Can someone help me with the correct way to do this? Thanks!

**Select HTML Markup:**

```
<select id="mode"><option value="local" style="z-index:2000;">Local</option>
<option value="region" style="z-index:2000;">Region</option>
<option value="global" style="z-index:2000;">Global</option>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function setMode(mode) {

switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'local':
        m = 0;
        break;
    case 'region':
        m = 1;
        break;
    case 'global':
        m = 2;
        break;
} 
socket.emit('setMode', m);
}
```

**Button HTML Markup:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-md mode" type="button" id="global" value="global" style="width:80px;height:28px;"><p>Global</p></button>

<button class="btn btn-default btn-md mode" type="button" id="regional" value="region" style="width:80px;height:28px;"><p>Regional</p></button>

<button class="btn btn-default btn-md mode" type="button" id="local" value="local" style="width:80px;height:28px;"><p>Local</p></button>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "But when I try to re-map the javascript to the buttons, it won't work"?

Comment: Right now the function setMode(mode) is linked to the select input. I want to link it to the 3 buttons instead.

Comment: Can you show how you're binding `setMode` to buttons click?